# How do we bypass our hosted exchange server's "security feature" that always requires credentials?

Tags: exchange, outlook, credentials

I read this post:

[How to stop Outlook 2007 asking for credentials when using RPC over HTTPS](https://serverfault.com/questions/39537/how-to-stop-outlook-2007-asking-for-credentials-when-using-rpc-over-https)

However, we don't have control over the back end server. This is controlled by a third party we are using for hosted exchange. They informed me that they have configured the server to require a user's credentials (password) every time the local Outlook client is opened. They also informed me there is no workaround, but I find it hard to believe I can't configure our own XP machines to remember a password, even if it means additional software.

Is this really the situation, or is there a workaround they aren't telling me about?

Answer (score 1):

Outlook will transparently authenticate to Exchange if logged-on with a credential in the same (or a trusted) domain as the Exchange Server computer is located.

You don't have that, so you're getting prompted for credentials.

One "workaround" would be to have your client computers joined to the domain where Exchange is being hosted. I seriously doubt your provider would do such a thing.

There's some talk in an article that I'm seeing that indicates that there may be a way to do this using the password caching functionality in Windows: http://www.andreasroom.com/blog/archive/2005/06/17/RPCHTTP.aspx  I've never tried this before and I'm a little dubious that it would work. It's worth a shot, though, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a funny way kerberos works is that if your login names and passwords in your local domain match the same as the exchange host then pass through authentication will work and allow you in despite different domain names.

I'm not an expert in this area though, Evan's answer is pretty solid.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RPC over HTTP to connect to your Exchange server, and the authentication method is set to basic on the server then you will be asked for your credentials everytime and there is very little you can do about this. If they are using NTLM authentication then you should be able to save your credentias

Answer (score 0):

Using the following command:

cmdkey /add:exchange.server.com /user:username /pass:password

you can save the credentials and NTLM will use the supplied user/pass when authenticating to the exchange.server.com.